# Using Clojure with an annotation-based REST Server

Tags: rest, clojure, jax-rs

I am considering writing a REST Server using Clojure.

I have experience using [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) with Java. It uses annotations to associate URLs, *template parameters*, and query parameters with Java classes, methods, and method parameters. I believe that the [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) REST Server also uses annotations (since it, too, is based on JAX-RS).

Is it possible to use these frameworks with Clojure? Is there an official way to associate annotations with functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer in the forth-coming book "Clojure Programming", by Chas Emerick, Brian Carper, and Christophe Grand.

If you define a new type with `deftype`, you can add annotations the newly created class:

```
(ns my.resources
  (:import (javax.ws.rs Path PathParam Produces GET)))

(definterface PersonService
  (getPerson [^Integer id]))

(deftype ^{Path "/people/{id}"} PersonResource []
  PersonService
  (^{GET true                                                
     Produces ["text/plain"]}
    getPerson
    [this ^{PathParam "id"} id]           
    ; blah blah blah    
  ))
```

I'm not sure if this will work with `gen-class`. I'll need to experiment.

Comment: this is overkill. I would do that with compojure

Comment: Not if you already have an existing large project that uses an annotation-based web framework and you need to convince coworkers that Clojure is a good fit.